# Why does Microsoft Excel evaluate MOD($44$, $8.8$) as $8.8$?

Tags: divisibility

As per my understanding, the formula function MOD in Microsoft excel should give the remainder value, after dividing two numbers.

So the formula `=MOD(40,8)` gives a value 0. This works as expected.

But the formula `=MOD(44,8.8)` gives a value 8.8, even-though `8.8*5 = 44`.

Could anyone help me understand why this gap?

Comment: This is really a question for Microsoft. For instance, see this Microsoft Community item ["Excel MOD fuction returns non zero remainder when there is no remainder"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-mod-fuction-returns-non-zero-remainder-when/988ac690-b2fc-4b0c-a919-61f4f918cc24) and others. Evidently, MOD's behavior is inconsistent with non-integer values.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the fact that computers truncate numbers when they round them. You can try for example:

`=MOD(44,8.8)`

`=MOD(44,8.7999999999)`

They provide different results even though they should be almost the same.

If you try a similar experience with an exact power of $2$ then the computer can compute the division without any loss of precision.

`=MOD(2.5,0.5)`

Comment: Sorry, you were right.

Comment: No worries! I got bitten many times with this problem...

Comment: Apple's Numbers spreadsheet program and LibreOffice get this right. If I run a simple C program to do the calculations in the obvious way using 32 bit floating point arithmetic, I get the right answer too (which is what I'd expect given the numbers involved here). So Microsoft's implementation is doing something odd, but I agree that you shouldn't rely on floating point approximations giving  precise results. Moral: don't use MOD without first converting the operands to integers in a way that is under your control.